# Issue inserting text into table from c# proc parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[tblMessages_Insert]", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // params
    SqlParameter messageText = new SqlParameter("@messageText", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    messageText.Value = message;

    // add params
    command.Parameters.Add(messageText);

    rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

So this works, the row gets inserted, however, my message was `"test message"`, and what ends up in the db is `"t"`.

Whats happening?

Comment: Need some more information: what type is "message"? How is the value of "message" set? What processing of the parameters is done in "[tblMessages_Insert]"? What size VarChar is specified in the parameter for [tblMessages_Insert]? What size varchar is specified in the column that is being inserted into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you give varchar a size in the proc..if you don't it will be 1 by default